# Mounting volume resulting empty folder in kubernetes minikube?

Tags: kubernetes, minikube

I have created a deployment and I wanted to mount the host path to the container, and when I check the container I see only empty folder.

Why am I getting this error? What can be the cause?

EDIT: I am using Windows OS.

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
 name: myservicepod6
 labels:
  app: servicepod
spec:
 replicas: 1
 selector:
  matchLabels:
   app: servicepod
 template:
  metadata:
    labels:
     app: servicepod
  spec:
   containers:
   - name: php
     image: php:7.2-apache
     command: ["/bin/sh", "-c"]
     args: ["service apache2 start; sleep infinity"]
     ports:
      - name: serviceport
        containerPort: 80
     volumeMounts:
      - mountPath: /var/www/html/
        name: hostvolume

   volumes:
    - name: hostvolume
      hostPath:
        path: /C/Users/utkarsh/pentesting/learnings/kubernetes/app/objectmanagement/deployments/src/*
```

EDIT FOR THE ANSWER -

I start the minkube -  `minikube start --mount-string="$HOME/test/src/code/file:/data"`

Then I changed the deployment file like below

Showing only volume part

```
  spec:
   volumes:
   - name: hostvolume
     hostPath:
      path: /C/Users/utkarsh/pentesting/learnings/kubernetes/app/deployments/src
   containers:
   - name: php
     image: php:7.2-apache
     command: ["/bin/sh", "-c"]
     args: ["service apache2 start; sleep infinity"]
     ports:
      - name: serviceport
        containerPort: 80
     volumeMounts: 
      - name: hostvolume
        mountPath: /test/src/code/file
```

When I log into the pod and went to the directory (/test/src/code/file) I found the directory empty

let me know what am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

After a detailed search and hit and trial method - Found the way

Only for minikube:-

First we need to mount the host folder into the directory name:

`minikube mount src/:/var/www/html`

Then we need to define hostPath and mountPath as

`/var/www/html`

Because now we have mount the folder to html folder.

```
volumes:
   - name: hostvolume
     hostPath:
      path: /var/www/html
   containers:
   - name: php
     image: php:7.2-apache
     command: ["/bin/sh", "-c"]
     args: ["service apache2 start; sleep infinity"]
     workingDir: /var/www/html
     ports:
      - name: serviceport
        containerPort: 80
     volumeMounts: 
      - name: hostvolume
        mountPath: /var/www/html
```

Comment: This works only one time! I am facing an error. `ls: cannot open directory '.': Input/output error`

Comment: Hi @Cloud Learner, any progress?

Comment: @MikolajS., I am using the above solution, It gives me error though but in 30 mins approx. I don't know why, why I am getting this error. And to remove the error, I need to restart the deployment and restart the mount. But still I am looking for better solution.

Comment: Could you please run `ls -ld /var/ww/html` both on the pod and minikube VM (you can SSH to minikube VM by running `minikube ssh` command) before and after error occurs? Is there any difference in the output?